# save and restore an array of custom objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an NSArray of custom objects that I want to save and restore. Can this be done with NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Was there any correct answer here?

Comment: @Joshua, thanks for providing the example code, it's very helpful.

Answer (score 26):

You can still use **[NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** if you archive your array into `NSData`.

For Archiving your array, you can use the following code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray] forKey:@"mySavedArray"];
```

And then for loading the custom objects in the array you can use this code:

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *savedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"mySavedArray"];
if (savedArray != nil)
{
        NSArray *oldArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedArray];
        if (oldArray != nil) {
                customObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray];
        } else {
                customObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
}
```

Make sure you check that the data returned from the user defaults is not `nil`, because that may crash your app.

The other thing you will need to do is to make your custom object comply to the `NSCoder` protocol. You could do this using the `-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder` and `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder` methods.

---

EDIT.

Here's an example of what you might put in the `-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder` and `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder` methods.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    [coder encodeObject:aLabel forKey:@"label"];
    [coder encodeInteger:aNumberID forKey:@"numberID"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    self = [[CustomObject alloc] init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        aLabel = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"label"];
        aNumberID = [coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"numberID"];
    }   
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Do I just have to add those method definitions or do I have to put code into those methods?

Comment: I've edited my post with an example of what you will need to put into those methods.

Answer (score 7):

`NSUserDefaults` cannot write custom objects to file, only ones it knows about (`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSString`, `NSData`, `NSNumber`, and `NSDate`). Instead, you should take a look at the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i), as well as the [NSCoding Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), if you're looking to save and restore custom objects to disk. Implementing the protocol is not terribly difficult, and requires very little work.

Answer (score 1):

Custom objects, no. NSUserDefaults only knows about a few basic types (NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary).

Could you use JSON (http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) to convert your custom object to a string representation, then save an array of those to Defaults? (Using the setObject:forKey: method).

Otherwise, you could look at using sqlite, NSCoder, or even resort to fopen.

Comment: Even though I'm using custom objects, they are stored in NSArray, which is what I'm trying to save. Shouldn't it work then?

Comment: If by "Shouldn't it work?" you mean "Can't I store custom objects in an NSArray?" the answer is yes. If you mean "Can't I store the array of custom objects in NSUserDefaults?" then the answer is no, because NSUserDefaults cannot store arbitrary objects.