# How to save NSMutableArray of "custom class objects" in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I've seen a few posts about how you can't save an object based `NSMutableArray` in `NSUserDefaults`, but that there is a way of doing it using `[NSKeyedArchiver]` and encoding it with `NSCoder` although I'm struggling to understand how to do it and was hoping someone could help.

```
Student *student1 = [Student studentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default"] withForename:@"John" withSurname:@"Smith" withAddress:@"3 Fake Road, Faketown, FA31 KEE" withDateOfBirth:[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"17-Jul-93"] withAge:24];
[studentArray addObject:student1];
```

I want this and a few other similar `Students` to be saved to my `NSMutableArray` `studentArray`. I want to then save this array to `NSUserDefaults` and load it back up again.

[I have seen this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648558/save-and-restore-an-array-of-custom-objects) which looks like is the correct answer to my question, but I need help implementing it to my code as I'm having difficulty understanding it! 
Thanks

Comment: you want save studentArray in userdafaults ?

Comment: @KKRocks thats correct, I need the array to be saved containing its properties like student Image, name, date of birth ect.

Comment: @Mahesh check my answer and add your property as i mentioned.

Comment: What didn't you understand about the linked question? What part is unclear? Because currently, the answers from KKRocks is just a simple adaption to your case, but without real more new informations or explanation. It's clearly a copy/paste from the other answer with a "Replace" (more or less).

Comment: @Larme The answer in the previous question was very clear, I just stupidly misunderstood where the `-(void)encodeWithCoder` and `initWithCoder` were placed. The first line in the answer below answered my question immediately.

Comment: If you had said that, we could have just pointed out that part of the answer: "to make your custom object comply to the NSCoder protocol", and oriented our answer/explains what it means to "comply to a protocol" (which is a basic and import knowledge).

Comment: It wasn't until I saw the answer below that this became clear to me. Thanks for the help anyway @KKRocks its much appreciated.

Comment: @mahesh mark as accept if answer helping you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add this in `Student`  class

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    [coder encodeObject:self.Forename forKey:@"keyForename"];
    // do same for all property
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    self = [[Student alloc] init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.Forename = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"keyForename"];
        // do same other property here
    }   
    return self;
}
```

**Store Array**

```
[studentArray addObject:student1];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:studentArray] forKey:@"mySavedArray"];
```

**Retrieve Array**

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *savedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"mySavedArray"];
if (savedArray != nil)
{
        NSArray *oldArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedArray];
        if (oldArray != nil) {
                customObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray];
        } else {
                customObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
}
```

Comment: This has worked excellently, although the only issue I'm having now is that the studentImage isn't saving. I have used `[coder encodeObject:self.studentImage forKey:@"keyStudentImage"];` but when loading the array, images don't load?

Comment: I've worked it out, don't worry: `[coder encodeObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.studentImage) forKey:@"keyStudentImage"];` in the `encodeWithCoder` and `self.studentImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"keyStudentImage"]];` in the `initWithCoder`. Thanks Again KKRocks